# How to change the axis label when using a field parameter?

Tags: visualization, powerbi-desktop

In a bar chart, I'm using a field parameter slicer to toggle between different time frames (Year, Month, Day). For reasons, the labels on the slicer used to select the time frame and the labels on the chart have to be different.

Here's an example of what I mean:
[image]

I tried two things: adding a new column in the Field Parameter table that Switches between labels based on the chosen parameter (this worked for a custom Legend); and creating a new table with the the Value:Label mapping and 1:1 relationship with the slicer.

My next attempt will be a hacky 'free-floating' label atop the slicer Title but was wondering if there's a more elegant solution than that?

Comment: Hacky, free-floating label worked—just added a card with the `label` column using either of the two approaches in the question.